# I'd like to find the formula for this triangle number sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

This is a numeric triangle that came up in a problem I'm trying to solve. I got this sequence using the brute force approach (Javascript):

```
function f(s, b){
  if(s == 0 || b == 0) return 0;
  if(s > b) return 0;
  if(s == 1 || b == 1 || b == s) return 1;

  let sum = 0;
  for(let i=0; i<Math.min(s, b); i++){
    sum += (i + 1) * f(s-i, b-s);
  }

  return sum;
}
```

Result for the first few numbers (10 x 10).

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
0 0 0 1 3 5 8 12 16 21 
0 0 0 0 1 4 7 12 20 30 
0 0 0 0 0 1 5 9 16 28 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 6 11 20 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 7 13 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 8 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

I'm not very good at combinatorics (or math in general). I'd like to understand how I can change the brute force approach so that I can get the sequence without iterating all numbers from `0` to `min(s, b)`. I've attempted building the sequence in many ways, but it's mostly by trying random multiplications and sums, so I don't think I'll end up having the correct formula soon with this approach.

### Background (what I'm trying to achieve):

We are trying to build a structure that's made out of blocks. Each structure has `s` stacks of blocks, and the total number of blocks is `b`. The structure must be convex, not concave. The goal is to count how many different structures for each pair of `s` and `b` values can be built. For example, if the stack number is the same as the block number, we can only build one, because all blocks are being used for the base. If the block count is less than the stack count, we can build none. If `s < b`, then there are many ways to build a convex structure.

Comment: Would you have some context for the function $f$ ? What need does it fulfill? I'm looking for an answer along the lines of "with the function f I'm trying to solve a problem where ... "

Comment: That looks like https://oeis.org/A072704.

Comment: @MattiP. We are trying to build a structure that's made out of blocks. Each structure has `s` stacks of blocks, and the total number of blocks is `b`. The structure must be convex, not concave. The goal is to count how many different structures for each pair of `s` and `b` values can be built. For example, if the stack number is the same as the block number, we can only build one, because all blocks are being used for the base. If the block count is less than the stack count, we can build none. If `s < b`, then there are many ways to build a convex structure.

Comment: @ChrisVilches Thank you for the clarification, this is actually a critical clarification in my opinion.

Comment: You seem to have come across the sequence at https://oeis.org/A072704 , as @MartinR has observed. I suspect there is no non-recursive formula because if there were one it would be likely to appear there.

Comment: @MichaelLugo Thanks. I don't really understand how my sequence relates to the one you and Martin posted. I tried to sum up some values but I don't get the same numbers.

Comment: You don't sum them up!  You read your numbers (the non-zero ones) one column at a time.  (This isn't obvious if you haven't wasted too much time looking at OEIS.)

Comment: @MichaelLugo holy cow, now I see it! It's exactly the same. Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisVilches The illustration at https://oeis.org/A001523/a001523.gif might help clarify that OEIS actually refers to the same thing as you, and not just some other thing that happens to have the same count.  (In that image they have added up the columns, to get 1, 2, 4, 8, 15, 27, ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it. It requires two functions. I'm not sure about the function naming, and maybe it can be refactored into one function, but it works this way, and I was able to bring the complexity from $O(n^3)$ to $O(n^2)$, so I'm happy with it.

This is the C++ code:

```
ll dp(int s, int b) {
  if (s == 0 || b == 0) return 0;
  if (s > b) return 0;
  if (s == 1 || b == 1 || b == s) return 1;
  if (memo[s][b] != -1) return memo[s][b];
  ll result = dp(s, b - s) + 2 * dp(s - 1, b - 1) - dp(s - 2, b - 2);
  return memo[s][b] = result;
}

int calculate(int s, int b) {
  if (s == 1 || b == 1 || b == s) return 1;
  ll sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < min(s, b); i++) {
    sum += (i + 1) * dp(s - i, b - s);
  }
  return (int)sum;
}
```

Then get the desired value (read the question statement to understand the problem) as `calculate(3, 6)` (i.e. ways to create a convex structure with 3 stacks and a total of 6 blocks).

Note: `ll` is `typedef long long int ll;`. The `memo` variable is for memoization.